# What exactly does "User.Read" give permission to?

Tags: office365, single-sign-on, azure-ad-graph-api

often Office365 SSO apps ask for "User.Read" right or "Sign in and read user profile".
But what exactly can these apps read from the user (profile) when they are given those rights?
Is there perhaps a privacy or security issue to consider?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about other sites that use SSO, or for your own? The read permission depends on the features you're using. For example, AAD, Graph, 365. etc. The list of default permissions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions?context=/azure/active-directory/roles/context/ugr-context).For your ask, 365 is pulling profile information from AAD. For your question about security issues, it depends if you're the user or the owner. If you're the site owner you can make custom roles and change what the user has read access to. If you're the user, you are notified of what info you consent to provide. So the only security concerns are what you deem comfortable. Please let me know if you have any questions and I can help you further!

Comment: Please forgive me for not following up sooner.
But the link to the default permissions did not clarify what I wanted to know.
In the "Request API Permissions" section of API Permisssions in Azure AD the caption at "user.read"  states: 'Allow users to sign-in to the app, and allows the app to read the profile on signed-in users. It also allows the app to read basic company information of signed-in users'
My question was: what information can the app see specifically?